# Visualforce pages does not trigger session time out. Any thoughts?

Tags: visualforce

i have watched this when i leave the visualforce pages in my browser, it does not trigger session time out. But the standard pages does. Is that anything i need to add to my visualforce page or apex code to make this happen? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: VF pages shouldn't behave differently from 'standard' pages with regards to session time out. Unless the page keeps doing requests to the server (e.g. apex:actionpoller). Does an empty visualforce page behave the same way?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a deeper look into this. There is no actionpoller used in my page.